# Rails 3.2 Devise Omniauth-facebook and koala

Tags: postgresql, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth, koala-gem

I am trying intergrate Koala into a devise omniauth-facebook app. For some reason i cannot post to user's wall. I created a second app which doesn't use devise and all works and i realise that the only difference is that **oauth_expires_at** I am having problems saving the oauth_expires_at returned by facebook.

```
  # Facebook
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
          unless user
            user = User.create(  name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                                 provider:auth.provider,
                                 uid:auth.uid,
                                 email:auth.info.email,
                                 image:auth.info.image,
                                 oauth_token:auth.credentials.token,
                                 password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                                 )
          end
        user
  end
```

I have tried

```
#oauth_expires_at:auth.credentials.expires_at.to_datetime,
#oauth_expires_at:auth.Time.at(auth['credentials'].expires_at),
#oauth_expires_at:Time.at(@auth[:credentials][:expires_at]).to_datetime,
```

How do i convert the facebook time response to PostgreSQL datetime format. Please help. Or does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `oauth_expires_at` is not causing the problem after all. I stand corrected.